# Cosmos DB: Getting document id from exception upon conflict

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos DB returns a `DocumentClientException` with a status of `409 Conflict` when trying to insert a document with unique keys that match an existing document (cf. [unique keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys), [exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet)).

Is it possible to get the id of the document from the exception without querying the db again?

Comment: Wouldn't the id be the same as the item you are trying to add as it is returning a conflict?

Comment: Not if I use other unique keys that are not the partition key (details in the unique keys link I posted).

Comment: Oh now i get it. You might have a conflict on some fields that might be unique key but you want the id of that item. The id however isn't unique if you have a partition that isn't the id column itself right?

Comment: @yngling  Per my understanding,there's no such callback method when you create  document in cosmos db so far. If you do want to get the conflict id, you need to retrieve the db with the conflict item.

Comment: @Elfocrash That's correct, I want the id of the document.